# Use of a code in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a doubt in jquery

why we use the code `$(document).ready(function() { .... });`?

what is the use of that code in beginning.

what is the difference between

```
alert (' .... ')
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert(' ... ')
)};
```

Comment: Alert is a bad example of how $(document).ready() works. Unless you have a selector in that alert. Lets say you want to select a div with ID="test". If you have the script at the top of the page, it will not work. Because the script ran before the div got added to the DOM. If you put the selector inside of a $(document).ready(function(){}); it will only run once everything has been added in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are working with jQuery, the following usually happens:

1. You load a static HTML page.
2. You manipulate that HTML page using js/jQuery.

Usually, you want the static HTML page to finish loading/initialising before you start changing it with jQuery. Wrapping your jQuery in this statement

```
$(document).ready(function() { .... });
```

ensures that your jQuery will not execute until the the HTML page says 'I have finished loading'. You can read more here:

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 2):

The use of $(document).ready means that anything you write within that statement is carried out **AFTER** the page has finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

The jquery documentation states that the ready event is triggered when the DOM is fully loaded, in other words when the HTML document, excluding the images, videos, external sources, etc. , is loaded.

Let's say if your jquery statement is put in the middle of the statement, and you claim the jQuery plugin at the HTML head. 
Without

```
$(document).ready(function(){...});
```

You may be in trouble when the actions involve elements which is put after this statement because this command will be executed at once.

Answer (score 1):

**$(document)** - Here,document is a selector. We can also use other selectors (Eg: Class or ID selector). In other words, we can select one or more elements from aHTML page.
**ready(function()** - Here, ready refers to ready event. It can be replaced by other events too.
**{    some code;   });**- This refers to the code which will execute when the event specified above occurs. 
So, **$(document).ready(function() { some code; });** means that the code inside will only execute when the whole webpage (document) has finished loading (ready event).

---

Next part of your question, consider this code:
jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<form action="other.html">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now the alert box will only display when you click on Submit button (perform submit event on the form).

Now consider the code:

```
alert("Alert is displayed");
```

This will generate an alert box without being triggered by any event. 
In most cases, you would want an alert to trigger only on particular events or conditions.